# Convert yuv420p to rgb888 in C

Tags: c, algorithm, rgb, yuv

I'm trying to convert planar YUV (yuv420p) to RGB24 in C.

I'm not controlling the input, and have the YUV data as 3 separate buffers, one for **Y**, one for **U** and one for **V**.

I want to create a single output RGB buffer from these 3 input buffers.

I followed the following schema on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.27UV420p_.28and_Y.27V12_or_YV12.29_to_RGB888_conversion) but I have a problem with my code, since the output image have wrong colors.

Here is my function (excuse the ulgyness…)

```
static uint8_t* yuv420p_to_rgb2(const uint8_t* y, const uint8_t* u, const uint8_t* v, const size_t width, const size_t height)
{
    const size_t size = width * height;
    uint8_t* rgb = (uint8_t*)calloc((size * 3), sizeof(uint8_t));

    int uv_index = 0, pass = 0;
    int b,g,r;
    uint8_t* ptr = rgb;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i += 6)
    {
        if (pass == 2)
        {
            pass = 0;
            uv_index += 3;
        }
        int y1 = y[i];
        int y2 = y[i+1];
        int y3 = y[i+2];
        int y4 = y[i+3];
        int y5 = y[i+4];
        int y6 = y[i+5];

        int u1 = u[uv_index];
        int u2 = u[uv_index+1];
        int u3 = u[uv_index+2];

        int v1 = v[uv_index];
        int v2 = v[uv_index+1];
        int v3 = v[uv_index+2];
        //1
        r = 1.164 * (y1 - 16) + 1.596 * (v1 - 128);
        g = 1.164 * (y1 - 16) - 0.813 * (v1 - 128) - 0.391 * (u1 - 128);
        b = 1.164 * (y1 - 16) + 2.018 * (u1 - 128);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(r);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(g);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(b);
        //2
        r = 1.164 * (y2 - 16) + 1.596 * (v1 - 128);
        g = 1.164 * (y2 - 16) - 0.813 * (v1 - 128) - 0.391 * (u1 - 128);
        b = 1.164 * (y2 - 16) + 2.018 * (u1 - 128);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(r);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(g);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(b);
        //3
        r = 1.164 * (y3 - 16) + 1.596 * (v2 - 128);
        g = 1.164 * (y3 - 16) - 0.813 * (v2 - 128) - 0.391 * (u2 - 128);
        b = 1.164 * (y3 - 16) + 2.018 * (u2 - 128);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(r);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(g);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(b);
        //4
        r = 1.164 * (y4 - 16) + 1.596 * (v2 - 128);
        g = 1.164 * (y4 - 16) - 0.813 * (v2 - 128) - 0.391 * (u2 - 128);
        b = 1.164 * (y4 - 16) + 2.018 * (u2 - 128);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(r);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(g);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(b);
        //5
        r = 1.164 * (y5 - 16) + 1.596 * (v3 - 128);
        g = 1.164 * (y5 - 16) - 0.813 * (v3 - 128) - 0.391 * (u3 - 128);
        b = 1.164 * (y5 - 16) + 2.018 * (u3 - 128);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(r);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(g);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(b);
        //6
        r = 1.164 * (y6 - 16) + 1.596 * (v3 - 128);
        g = 1.164 * (y6 - 16) - 0.813 * (v3 - 128) - 0.391 * (u3 - 128);
        b = 1.164 * (y6 - 16) + 2.018 * (u3 - 128);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(r);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(g);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(b);

        pass++;
    }

    return rgb;
}
```

Result (top image is my result, bottom is what it should be):
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to add the alpha layer, this may help (but this is quite long to explain and not well formed in my head so I can't right now)

Comment: Adding an alpha channel is trivial but I don't see the point, it won't change a thing…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're getting the U and V values incorrectly.

The U and V values for pixel (`i`, `j`) are :

```
u[((j / 2) * (width / 2)) + (i / 2)];
v[((j / 2) * (width / 2)) + (i / 2)];
```

So, try a loop like this :

```
for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        int yy = y[(j * width) + i];
        int uu = u[((j / 2) * (width / 2)) + (i / 2)];
        int vv = v[((j / 2) * (width / 2)) + (i / 2)];

        r = 1.164 * (yy - 16) + 1.596 * (vv - 128);
        g = 1.164 * (yy - 16) - 0.813 * (vv - 128) - 0.391 * (uu - 128);
        b = 1.164 * (yy - 16) + 2.018 * (uu - 128);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(r);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(g);
        *ptr++ = CLAMP(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it pseudo-language?

Comment: @Rilakkuma : like in the question, this code is in C.

Comment: For those looking for CLAMP(), this works nicely:
`uint8_t clamp(int16_t value) {
    return value<0 ? 0 : (value>255 ? 255 : value);
}`